# Change $resource parameter AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, resources

I'm using AngularJS $resource service.

After creating an instance of the resource, I'm trying to change one of the GET params.

The problem is that i keep getting the original value.

any ideas?

regards,

Iliya

Comment: Please include some code.

Comment: Without code, we literally cannot help you.